# When ever i am clicking login button my html page is open again on other tab how can i fix this issue?

Tags: javascript, html

When ever I am clicking login button my html page is open again on other tab how can I fix this issue?
I have made a html form so when ever I click on login than html page is opening in new tab how to fix this problem

## my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script2.js"></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js"
    ></script>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="phone-app-demo"></div>
        <div class="form-data">
          <form id="myForm" action="" target="_blank">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email"   id="email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password"   id="name">
            <button class="form-btn"  onclick="sendMail()">Log in</button>
            <span class="has-separator">Or</span>
            <a class="facebook-login" href="#">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> Log in with Facebook
            </a>
            <a class="password-reset" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
          </form>
          <div class="sign-up">
            Don't have an account? <a href="#">Sign up</a>
          </div>
          <div class="get-the-app">
            <span>Get the app.</span>
            <div class="badges">
              <img src="./images/app-store.png" alt="app-store badge">
              <img src="./images/google-play.png" alt="google-play badge">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have `onclick="sendMail()"` on that button... (?)

Comment: remove `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `target="_blank"` attribute from your `form` tag to avoid opening in another tab.